# Disassmbling with IDA python for extract instruction

Tags: python, arm, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I am using IDA Python for extract the instructions of a binary. But unfortunately it does not print some instructions completely. For example, BCC, BCS, BEQ are printed as B. Is there any way to correct this problem?
Here is my code!!!

```
for function_ea in idautils.Functions():
    for ins in idautils.FuncItems(function_ea):
        if idaapi.isCode(idaapi.getFlags(ins)):
            print idc.GetMnem(ins)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that (I checked this on my databases for ARM):

```
import idautils

for function_ea in idautils.Functions():
    for ins in idautils.FuncItems(function_ea):
        if idaapi.isCode(idaapi.getFlags(ins)):
            cmd = idc.GetDisasm(ins)
            mnem = cmd.split(' ')[0]
            print mnem
```

From IDA manual:

> Get instruction mnemonics
>
> ea - linear address of instruction
>
> returns: 0 - no instruction at the specified location
>
> note: this function may
>   not return exactly the same mnemonics as you see on the screen.

So, if you want to see full mnemonic name you should use external dissasembler/plugin or parse disassembly line.

Answer (score 4):

`BCC`, `BCS` and `BEQ` are conditional branch instructions and therefore have same opcode. Everything after the `B` is the condition code, where:

- EQ is equal
- CC is carry clear
- CS is carry set

See [1](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/Cihfddaf.html) and [2](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/CEGBHJCJ.html) for more information.